# CPU cost in copy_to_user()

Tags: c, linux-kernel

how much CPU time is consumed in using copy_to_user() function in Linux kernel for copying data from kernel space to user space.

Ex->
if we have to copy 80 bytes of data from kernel space to a buffer in user space so we call copy_to_user() & it copy the data ...& if we add a timer at the starting of copy_to_user() & stop the timer when it completed coping then how much time will be elapsed in nano seconds...can we calculate it or any estimation.
Because i have to copy a lot of data buffers per second from kernel space to user space using Kernel-loadable modules.

Comment: about 1/4 cycle per character. Another ~4 cycles per character are spent waiting for the L1 cache to fill or drain.

Comment: @wildplasser seems like an answer, why don't you post it?

Comment: Basically because the question is wrong. CPU ticks are not a measure, once the memory bus bandwidth is saturated. And there may be other barriers slowing down the execution: pagefaults, buslocks, TLB misses (??) Anyway: for trivial operations like memcpy, the CPU is about 10 times as fast as the memory channel.